# Why is there no info reaching this element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a react application and in one component, I am sending some data to another component by using an API, while using useEffect. When I look at the network tab, I see the API there, but the coins variable is for some reason not included in the link. What's the reason that this could be happening? Here is my code:

```
import {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react";

import CoinItem from "./CoinItem";

const CoinList = (props) => {
  const [coinInfo, setCoinInfo] = useState([]);

  let coinData = [];

  var groups = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < props.coins.length; i++) {
    let coinName = props.coins[i].coinName;

    if (!groups[coinName]) {
      groups[coinName] = [];
    }

    groups[coinName].push(props.coins[i].coinAmount);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let tickers = Object.keys(groups);
    let coins = Object.keys(groups).join(",");
    let currency = "cad";

    let priceDataUrl = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${coins}&vs_currencies=${currency}`;

    fetch(priceDataUrl)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        tickers.forEach((coin) => {
          coinData.push({
            coinName: coin,
            coinAmount: groups[coin].reduce(
              (a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)
            ),
            coinPrice: data[coin.toLowerCase()].cad,
          });
        });

        setCoinInfo(coinData);
      });
  }, []);

  return ( 
    <table className="w-full">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Coin</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody> 
      {
        coinData.length > 0 &&
        coinData.map((coin) => ( 
          <CoinItem 
            key={coin.coinName}
            coinAmount={coin.coinAmount}
            coinName={coin.coinName}
            coinPrice={coin.coinPrice}
            coinData={coinData}
          />
        ))
      } 
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default CoinList;
```

Comment: fetch(priceDataUrl) is the one that gets no data?

Comment: Log `data` immediately after you get it in the `then((data) => { console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));`. Also verify your URL is correct. Check your Network tab in Developer Tools and make sure the API call is returning data and not an error. All of this is basic debugging these days.

Answer (score 0):

On each render `coinData` is set to `[]`, then your JSX return expression is evaluated. Since `[].length > 0` evaluates to `false`, your `<CoinItem>` is never rendered.

Consider instead using `coinInfo`, which is initialized as `[]`, but when your `fetch` completes is updated via the `setCoinInfo` call, prompting another render of the component with the updated value for `coinInfo`.

Note: you will want to move `let coinData = []` into your `useEffect` hook, otherwise the hook will always refer to the same array initialized on the initial render, which means that `coinInfo` will wind up with duplicated information if you ever change the `useEffect` dependency array.

```
const CoinList = (props) => {
  const [coinInfo, setCoinInfo] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const groups = {};

    props.coins.forEach(({ coinName, coinAmount }) => {
      if (!groups[coinName]) {
        groups[coinName] = [];
      }

      groups[coinName].push(coinAmount);
    }
 
    const tickers = Object.keys(groups);
    const coins = Object.keys(groups).join(",");
    const currency = "cad";

    let priceDataUrl = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${coins}&vs_currencies=${currency}`;

    fetch(priceDataUrl)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const coinData = tickers.map((coin) => ({
          coinName: coin,
          coinAmount: groups[coin].reduce(
            (a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)
          ),
          coinPrice: data[coin.toLowerCase()][currency],
        });

        setCoinInfo(coinData);
      });
  }, []);

  return ( 
    <table className="w-full">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Coin</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody> 
      {
        coinInfo.length > 0 &&
        coinInfo.map((coin) => ( 
          <CoinItem 
            key={coin.coinName}
            coinAmount={coin.coinAmount}
            coinName={coin.coinName}
            coinPrice={coin.coinPrice}
            coinData={coinInfo}
          />
        ))
      } 
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

Comment: The problem with putting coinData in the useEffect hook is that it keeps calling that API and gets into a loop, causing a memory leak.

Comment: @HTMLDeveloper That's not correct. See the code example I provided.

Comment: Your code block doesn't work, because it gives me errors on the bottom pertaining to the fact that coinData is not defined.

Comment: @HTMLDeveloper Sorry, forgot to update those to `coinInfo` as I mentioned.

Comment: Tried the updated codeblock, it gives me this error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {coinName, coinAmount, coinPrice}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. I also updated my post for more context on what's happening.

Comment: @HTMLDeveloper Sounds like you are trying to render `props.coinData` inside of `CoinItem` (e.g. doing something like `<div>{coinData}</div>`). Not sure what the intent of something like this, or why you're passing `coinData` down in the first place, though, so I can't really suggest the right solution other than just telling you to remove that.